# Is there a way to have Paw sort JSON response keys alphabetically when displayed?

Tags: paw-app

Is there a way to have Paw sort JSON response key-value pairs by key alphabetically when displayed?  This would make it easier to find entries at a glance without resorting to using a key path.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Paw has a "Sort Keys" option under Preferences -> Formatting, in the JSON section.

[image: paw preferences, formatting tab]